# .htaccess rewriterule syntax

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make some rewrite rules for inclusion in .htaccess with the following conditions:

```
(www).site.com/setup   --> redirects to: www.site.com/setup
demo.site.com/setup    --> redirects to: www.site.com/demo/setup
(www).site.com/xyz   --> redirects to: www.site.com/web/xyz
demo.site.com/xyz    --> redirects to: www.site.com/demo/web/xyz
```

Note that (www) means the user can both input and not input www and "xyz" can be any string but different than the keyword "setup" (due to the first two rules).

This is what I tried (using [L] to make exceptions) but I'm not sure if it is ok enough:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} demo.
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} /setup
RewriteRule /demo/setup [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} /setup
RewriteRule /setup [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} demo.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ www.site.com/demo/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ www.site.com/web/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Luciano

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: what have you tried? caus people does need a lot thing, but if you dont try it does not count here mate

Comment: I added my try but not sure about it.

Comment: I just change some conditions... you let me know what you think.

Comment: 1st rule: `(www).site.com/setup   --> redirects to: www.site.com/setup` appears to be same URL on both sides.

Comment: right, it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(demo)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(setup)/?$ http://www.%2/%1/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(demo)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(xyz)/?$ http://www.%2/%1/web/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^demo\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(xyz)/?$ /web/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: wow, this is quite different from what I did. I am gonna give it try and let you know! Thanks!